# Linking SCIP to existing project

Tags: c++, eclipse, scip

I've been trying to use SCIP in a personal project. I managed to compile the scipoptsuite-3.2.1 fine (even if the resulting folder is in my Download folder, because I'm a slob), but I can't seem to make it work.

I work on Eclipse CDT, I could link the headers just fine, the functions are recognized but I have undefined references all over the place. When I try to link scip's library (libscip.a) however, I have the following error :

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/myusername/Downloads/scipoptsuite-3.2.1/scip-3.2.1/lib/libscip.a(fileio.o): undefined reference to symbol 'gzdopen'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Segmentation_2D] Error 1
```

To solve that, I added the command -lz but .. That doesn't work either.

- If I link as such : -lscip -lz     -> Compilation starts going in an infinite loop
- If I link as such : -lz -lscip     -> DOS missing
- If I link as such : -lz -lscip -lz -> Compilation starts going in an infinite loop

I just don't know what to try next, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT -

I have now redone the installation using the flags ZLIB=false, READLINE=false and ZIMPL=false. I also used the command INSTALLDIR="" to correctly place the libraries, headers and binaries in my system (I had to edit the Makefile to do that since it would originally link to ../thePath, with thePath="/usr/local", for example).

However, it still doesn't work. What I thought was a infinite loop is in fact a massive number of errors (13.000+) which seem to be unresolved call of every function. (I only compile with -lscip now).

What can I do now ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `libscip` is not the correct library for your application. You should rather use `libscipopt` from within the `lib/` directory of the SCIP Optimization Suite (run `make scipoptlib`).

`libscip` only contains pure SCIP code and will only work together with

- `liblpi{spx,cpx,...}` to have an LP solver
- `libnlpi` to have an NLP solver
- `libobjscip` for C++ support

`libscipopt` is supposed to combine all these libraries into one for easier usage.